# Any trick to fold and map Applicative at once

Tags: scala, scala-cats

For instance, I have an easy code snippet:

```
import cats.instances.option._
import cats.syntax.option._
import cats.syntax.apply._

val a = 1.some
val b = 2.some

(a, b).mapN(_ + _)
```

I wish to fold this to result or `0`.
Are there any alternatives to `.getOrElse(0)`?

Maybe a kind of:

```
(a, b).foldN(0)(_ + _) // foldN actually does not exists
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do you have to use a tuple there? If you used `NonEmptyList` or `NonEmptyChain` you can simply do

```
NonEmptyList.of(1.some, 2.some).reduce // Some(3)
```

or

```
NonEmptyList.of(1.some, 2.some).reduceMap(_.getOrElse(0)) // 0
```

or any other combination utilizes of `NonEmpty*` or `Traverse`.

You cannot run away from `getOrElse` entirely. At some point you have to provide some `Option[Int] => Int` mapping, either in `foldMap`, `reduceMap` or after `fold`ing/`reduce`ing. You might replace that with `fold` on `Option` or something else but no `Applicative` utility would do this for you as exiting the context `F` is not a part of an `Applicative` interface (more like a `Comonad`).